# Is it possible to see if a record was deleted, but has been since undeleted?

Tags: delete, undelete

Curious to know if there's a way to see that a Lead or Contact was deleted, but subsequently undeleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use [Event Monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Event-Log-Files&language=en_US&type=1) to detect when records were deleted and subsequently restored, because all of that information is logged, but there's no out-of-the-box free feature that does this. You would have to write your own logic (e.g. a trigger that populates a custom field when a record is undeleted).

Comment: It would have to be the undelete trigger no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, that's what I meant.